# how to split the colon(:) separated string value into next column in csv file using awk or sed

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, sed

i have below data and i would like to split the colon(:) separated value into next column

Sample data

```
htttp://example.com, 80
http://lookup/bin/search, 80
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8115,80
century.testing.external-abc03:6112,80
century.testing.external-abc03:6112,80
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8115,80
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8117,80
```

Desired output

```
htttp://example.com, 80
http://lookup/bin/search, 80
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8115
century.testing.external-abc03,6112
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8117
```

Note: If http then print 80 and https then print 443, if there is any number in the URL then print that number instead 80

Tried below AWK command but not getting expected output.

```
awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1],a[2]}'
```

Removing the duplicates as well

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: you have `split("|"..)` when you should have `split(":",...)`. Good luck.

Comment: i have tried that one too, but no luck @shellter

Comment: how would you expect `|` to split a field divided by `:`. Always show your best work please. Does your unexpected output have anything to do with the trailing `,80` I see in your data? You'll need to `sub(/,80/,"", $0)` that out too. Good luck.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: You want to drop the original second column too? `cut -d, -f1 input.csv | tr : ,`

Comment: @Shawn if there is any number in the URL then i need to print that number instead of 80.

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates even if they are not consecutive? Meaning, the 9-th line is the same as the second line (but all the lines in between are different) - then remove the 9-th line anyway? The answer is important; if you only need to remove consecutive duplicates, the solution can work on a stream; but if you need to de-duplicate globally, stream processing will not be possible.

Comment: @mathguy Need to remove the duplicates (column A and column B) matches in the rows then yes, need to delete .

Comment: Then your output is wrong - you may want to correct it. The first and the third line are duplicates.

Comment: oho yeah you are correct, thank you i will update it

Comment: @JamesBrown exactly, if i have http://example.com then port should be 80. If there is any number(port) in the URL then i need to print that number instead of 80

Comment: @JamesBrown edited

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty you mentioned ```https``` printing 443, but you never show any example in your 'sample data' that is https.  Will that sample data already have 443 instead of 80? Should we replace 80 with 443?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F'[:,]' '!a[$0]++{print $1","$2}'
```

This will work based upon my best interpretation of what you are asking for:

- no duplicates
- the field after the colon turned into its own CSV field
- the last column dropped

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk -F'[:,]' '!a[$0]++{print $1","$2}' < /path/to/input
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8115
century.testing.external-abc03,6112
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8117
```

Note that your desired output still shows a duplicate, I'm assuming this was an error.

Comment: Thank  you, i am trying now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt via sed. It does not take care of dupes. You could easily use a few Unix commands to eliminate the dupes but that is not what you have asked for. Perhaps someone else knows how to do it via sed ?

`sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\),.*/\1,\2/'`

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\),.*/\1,\2/' file_name
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8115
century.testing.external-abc03,6112
century.testing.external-abc03,6112
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8115
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8117
$
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not what you have asked for"? The OP explicitly asked to de-duplicate, and showed that in the desired output too. I almost downvoted your answer for this reason, but then I realized it's a (partial) correct answer. Please edit your answer to remove that false statement about what the OP requested.